# Composite view with collapsible list view

Tags: jquery-mobile, marionette

I am trying to render a composite view with the following template but I do not have a clue on how to accomplish it. The main idea is that each collapsible is a category with its items (something like a treeview). A category may or may not have items

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
   <h2>{{Category}}</h2>
   <ul id="Items" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
   </ul>
</div>
```

The composite view has attributes:

```
 attributes: function() {
            return {
               "data-role": "collapsible-set",
               "data-theme" : "b",
               "data-content-theme" : "a"
            };
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on the blog post I wrote on the subject: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/02/03/tutorial-nested-views-using-backbone-marionettes-compositeview/

Also, Derick's blog post on the subject could be of interest: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/

Comment: In the sample provided in your blog, what if we have a hero inside another hero (nested). How can this be accomplished?

Comment: See Derick's blog post: use a collection view for the top-level collection, then a composite view for each item in the top-level collection. Each element will then have its own collection recursively rendered using the same composite view.